# Visual C# localization: Resources DLLs generated only in obj/Debug/tempPE

Tags: resources, resx, visual-c#-express-2010

To internationalize&localize my Visual C# 2010 Express project I created `Resources.resx` and `Resources.fr.resx` containing key-value strings:

[image]

When I press `Rebuild`, two DLLs get created:

```
obj/Debug/tempPE/Properties.Resources.Designer.cs.dll
obj/Debug/tempPE/Properties.Resources.fr.Designer.cs.dll
```

Why in this odd location?
Should I embed those in my installer?
No other Resources DLL are generated anywhere so I have no choice, but it is scary to ship files coming from a "tempPE" folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Resource.fr.Designer.cs file. It should not be there. Resource.Designed.cs is enough.

Comment: I deleted `Resource.fr.Designer.cs` and now no DLL is generated for French anymore... are localizations included in the main project DLL?

Comment: I also deleted `Reosurces.fr.resx`, then re-added it by drag-and-drop from Windows Explorer, and now it works :-) DLL is generated correctly as `bin/fr/SparkleShare.resources.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Only the default language file needs an Access Modifier of Internal or Public. All other language files need "No code generation".

The obj folder you can ignore. It is there for the build process and for Visual Studio's purpose. All you need for your program to work is in bin. You can delete both folders, they will be recreated.